# Android Studio : Unable to resolve library class symbol

Tags: android, android-studio

When I'm trying to run my app on my samsung galaxy Tab 4 (lollipop 5.0.2) wtih API level 23, I have some build errors due to missing import files in DrawableWrapper class :

[image]
Android studio is unable to find NonNull, Nullable and Insets symbole class.

I tried most of the solutions on google : add android support external library, clean and build the project, use another API level (21, 22), I got the same error.

Have you any idea about this issue ?

Can you suggest me different potential solutions ?

Comment: add build.gradle file

Comment: change `Insets` to `android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable`

Comment: add `   compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's resolved for InsetDrawable class but NonNull and Nullable class are still not found

Comment: add `app/build.gradle` especially dependencies

Comment: I did it, I added   compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0' in app/build.gradle dependencies

Comment: i added answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `android.graphics.Insets` to `android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable`
2. Open `app/build.gradle` and add in dependencies `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'`